# Count occurence of list of couple in python and append result to new list with all the elements in the first list

Tags: python, list, counter, find-occurrences

I have this:

```
list = [
    (('hash1', 'hash2'), (436, 1403)),
    (('hash1', 'hash2'), (299, 1282)),
    (('hash2', 'hash3'), (1244, 30)),
    (('hash1', 'hash3'), (436, 1403)),
    (('hash3', 'hash4'), (299, 1282)),
    (('hash5', 'hash4'), (1244, 30)),
    ]
```

I need to count how many occurrences are for the 1st couple

So I do this:

```
out = Counter((x[0]) for x in list)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Counter({('hash1', 'hash2'): 2, ('hash2', 'hash3'): 1, ('hash1', 'hash3'): 1, ('hash3', 'hash4'): 1, ('hash5', 'hash4'): 1})
```

And it's okay, but the result I want is this:

```
'hash1','hash2,(436,1403)
```

I need the second value to, that can be random so in this case can be

```
(436, 1403) or `(299, 1282))`
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
Couple of hash, any couple of number of the hash1,hash2, N.occurrences
((hash1,hash2),(436,1403),2
```

There is a way to do this?

Comment: Which occurrences are you trying to count? your question is not clear and also your expected output

Comment: The Couple of Hash but in the result i need the number  for example 436, 1403.So for exaple "hash1" "hash2 , count 2 times, but i need to have in the final result "hash1,"hash2, 436,1403 , 2 like this

Comment: can you update your expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and
[itertools.chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice)

```
from itertools import groupby, chain
from random import choice

lst = [(('hash1', 'hash2'), (436, 1403)),
    (('hash1', 'hash2'), (299, 1282)),
    (('hash2', 'hash3'), (1244, 30)),
    (('hash1', 'hash3'), (436, 1403)),
    (('hash3', 'hash4'), (299, 1282)),
    (('hash5', 'hash4'), (1244, 30))]

for k, g in groupby(lst, lambda x: x[0]):
    g = list(chain.from_iterable(g))[1::2]
    print(k, choice(g), len(g))
```

**Output:**

```
('hash1', 'hash2') (299, 1282) 2
('hash2', 'hash3') (1244, 30) 1
('hash1', 'hash3') (436, 1403) 1
('hash3', 'hash4') (299, 1282) 1
('hash5', 'hash4') (1244, 30) 1
```

You can also use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html?highlight=collections#collections.defaultdict)

```
from random import choice
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(list)
for x in lst:
    res[x[0]].append(x[1])

for k, v in res.items():
    print(k, choice(v), len(v))
```